# TensorFlow not playing nicely with IPython

Tags: python, tensorflow, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to use TensorFlow from an IPython notebook. I've created a function that defines a placeholder an a variable. Since I'm a TensorFlow newbie, I did not initialize the variable properly and got an error saying I did not initialize a placeholder.

I have two cells, one with the function and one with a function call. No matter how much I fix the function (and rerun both cells, of course) I keep getting initialization errors even after I fix the bug.

The only way to get it to work is to restart the kernel, which pretty much beats the purpose of a notebook, I can just write a Python script.

Answer (score 1):

It is mostly speculation without seeing your code, but from what I read I believe to know what you are doing wrong.

When using Tensorflow inside a notebook you have to be especially careful not to confuse graph **building** code with **evaluation** code. You only need and should define the computational graph once at the beginning. Executing functions which define the graph again will just build another subgraph (this probably also goes for your function which defines the placeholder and variables). The [tf.global_variables_initializer](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/global_variables_initializer) operation should also only be executed once.

It is crucial to understand that the Tensorflow graph can not be dynamically handled by the notebook, because python does not actually control Tensorflow variables. Python in this case is just a meta language for defining the graph and initiating computations.

So in the notebook after initializing the graph exactly **once** you can only call functions which wrap Tensorflow graph **evaluation** code, not graph building code dynamically without resetting the kernel. Examples for such methods which only evaluate an existing graph are [session.run](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Session#run), other [tf.Session](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Session) methods or similar evaluation methods like [tensor.eval](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Tensor#eval).

So yea to make it clear, there is no way to change an already build graph without rebuilding it which in this case requires resetting the kernel, unless you just build new subgraphs over and over again (and initialize the new variables) but that will at some point use up all available memory.